Israeli reasons for judgment from 1961
can anyone help me find a copy of the Israeli Supreme Court’s 1961 reasons for judgment in
206/61
Communist Party of Israel v Mayor of Jerusalem ‎1723

Can you include an English translation? And, I would presume that what you really want is the opinion stating the reason for the judgment and not the judgment itself, which would just be a line or two saying who won.

@ohwilleke interesting - in Australia what you describe would be called the orders. The judgement is the orders and the opinion.

@ohwilleke The English title of the case would be ‘Communist Party of Israel v Mayor of Jerusalem’, but, as Dale explained, I meant what I said: in the Israeli legal system – as in England and Australia – there’s no such thing as an ‘opinion’, only an order which gives a simple outcome and a judgment which gives reasons.

@Zarka Fair enough. And, of course, the exact legal terms in the Israeli courts would be in Hebrew rather than English anyway, so to some extent it boils down to a translation issue in the area of legal terminology.

I think פסיקת בג״צ can easily be translated as either "judgement" or "opinion" or "decision", depending on the language/dialect. The meaning is the same as "the opinion of the court" when discussing SCOTUS, for example.

This decision of the Israeli Supreme Court (as the Court of Justice) determined that it is permissible to publish posters which criticize the government and the governmental officials and policies, no matter how harshly. This is one of the case law precedents establishing the freedom of speech in Israel.
Didn't find the decision itself (doesn't show up in the digital search, probably hasn't been digitized), but found a bunch of references. The most interesting one is in this HUJI law review article (see p. 407, it includes excerpts from the decision, describes the rationale and the reasoning, and also cites the offensive text in question). The main reasoning, as described in the law review article, was that political speech enjoys absolute protection and doesn't fall under any criminal statute (libel, in this case).
To find non-digitized court documents you'll need to reach out to the court office, or check university libraries or legal services offices if you are in Israel. Nevo might have it (the law review article seems to be originally from there), but it requires a paid subscription.
A relatively recent discussion of this precedent was in בג״צ 316/03, in which the Court has determined that a libelous film should be permitted for public screening. The film was eventually banned in 2021 in a different court proceeding.

Wonder why the downvotes...
